# Prevent click on underlying div, react js

Tags: javascript, reactjs

My jsx:

```
return (
  <div onClick={this.clickondiv}>
   <i className="zmdi zmdi.." onClick={this.clickonicon} /> 
  </div>
)
```

How do I prevent the onClick event on the div when I click on the icon?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can stop the event from propegating up the DOM tree. In your clickonicon do this.

```
clickonicon(e){
    e.stopPropagation();
    //Rest of the clickonicon code
}
```